# Set a VFAT volume name non-destructively?

Tags: vfat

The only way I know to set VFAT volume name under Linux is `mkfs.vfat -n desired_name ...`, which obviously destroys volume's contents.

Is there a way to change the volume name non-destructively, as Windows does?

This name is conveniently used to name the volume on auto-mount.

(I'd gladly use a better FS, but all my cameras want only VFAT-formatted flash media.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dosfslabel` (from the same package as `mkfs.vfat`):

```
dosfslabel /path/to/device newlabel
```

Or `mlabel` from `mtools`:

```
mlabel -i /path/to/device ::newlabel
```

Comment: Interestingly, `dosfslabel` from current Debian stable was unable to set the label on a 16GB vfat volume, but the version from Ubuntu 12.04 worked.